# Turn a list into multiple dictionaries in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list like this:

```
original_list= ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
```

How would I be able to write a function to convert it into this:

```
converted_list= [{'A': 1}, {'B': 1}, {'C': 1}, {'D': 1}, {'E': 1}]
```

All the values in each dictionary are 1.

Thank you!

Comment: `converted_dict = dict.fromkeys(original_list, 1)` to form dict with multiple keys; `converted_list = [{i: 1} for i in original_list]` to get output from question.

Comment: You can also use
```Python
my_dict = {key: 1 for key in my_list}
```

Comment: That doesn't look useful, you'd better explain why you want that.

Comment: This looks similar to `collections.Counter(original_list)` what is the use of your output?

Comment: @Joseph That's not what OP wants

Comment: @OlvinRoght I think that would work. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
converted_list = [{s: 1} for s in original_list]
```